# Docker laravel php exec command

Tags: php, linux, laravel, docker, exec

Laravel 8.x
Docker

Simple code

```php
Route::get('/edit/{vId}', function(string $vId) use($vIdRegex) {
    $cmd = "$(which youtube-dl) --get-url -f best https://youtu.be/$vId";
    $res = exec($cmd, $output, $result_code);
    dd([
        'cwd' => getcwd(),
        'cmd' => $cmd,
        'output' => $output,
        'result_code' => $result_code,
        'res' => $res,
    ]);

})->name('edit');
```

But exec always returns 127 - command not found

youtube-dl is installed properly (if I use `sail shell` then it works perfectly)

If I run `which youtube-dl` in php, it runs properly

For some reason, php can't run non system commands (even if I specify any path it'll be always 127), ls, whoami, everything works, but not if I specify path to youtube-dl

Why :(

Comment: does it have executable permissions for the web user? Try running `chmod ugo+x /path/to/youtube-dl`